# How can I shut down my virus-infected remote desktop PC?

Tags: remote-desktop, virus, nod32, bitdefender

I have a remote PC connected with Remote Desktop as administrator. It was infected by a virus and therefore I can't run task manager or command run.

How can I restart or shut down my remote PC? Please consider that I don't have access to the task manager, comand run or even the task bar.

Comment: Are you able to make a right mouse click on the desktop ?

Comment: Yes I can right click on my desktop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are able to right click on the desktop:

1. Create a new text file.
2. Put "shutdown -s" inside.
3. Save the file, then rename it to something.bat.
4. Double-click.

Answer (score 2):

Right click (if you can) on the desktop and do new shortcut, and it is worth trying taskman.exe, but if you can't, type this - "shutdown -i" and you can set options from there.

If that fails, you can close your remote desktop session, and then reopen remote desktop connection, but do not click connect. Click options then programs and click "start the following program on connection" and it is worth trying to launch task manager or cmd through that method.

Lastly, you can try connecting through remote desktop via start > run (on your machine) then

mstsc /v: /admin (on newer)

mstsc /v: /console (on older)

and you should be connected to the console session which may be able to launch files if a virus stops you under another user (I know this sounds stupid, but sometimes I have found it to work).

Answer (score 1):

Click on an empty area on the desktop and press Alt+F4. This should bring up the shutdown menu.

Comment: no this don't work.